# React-native scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval doesn't work if called from javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, timer, react-native

I'm trying to execute a function every second with Objective-c to see if it improve the performance of the application, this is the [code](http://pastebin.com/PZkfyQCV).

If I execute the function startTimer from in the init it work and every second runner it's called, if instead I call it from JS it doesn't work. Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue, however, I found this code that works:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,   delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
  // Do Something Here
});
```